# what are the differences in timing for chess grading?

Tags: chess

Can you clear something up as regards rating time bands.

Official or standard grading I always assumed was an hour-and-a-half or more. Am I incorrect?

Is Blitz an hour or less?
Is Speedplay 0-15 mins?

FIDE or guidance appreciated.

Comment: This is a slightly different question than the linked duplicate because it asks what time controls are used for rating purposes, not what time controls are popular. This is an interesting (and surprisingly complicated) question.